# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in Visual Studio Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
 com/android/dx/command/Main  :  Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I installed Xamarin offline after installing, i created Sample app. But i got error Please Help me to solve this.

Comment: http://motzcod.es/post/149717060272/fix-for-unsupported-majorminor-version-520

Comment: Thanks @Jason . Its working